# Independent countDown in Javascript

Tags: javascript, countdown

I use [final countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/) to countdown timer. I provide an `enddate` and it works fine.

```
<div class="js-countdown" data-enddate="2019/1/21 15:54"></div>
```

my js:

```
var $clock = $('.js-countdown');
var d = new Date(Date.parse($clock.data("enddate").replace(/ /g, "T")));
  $clock.countdown(d, function(event) {
    $(this).text(
      event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
    );
  });
</script>
```

It really depends on user clock, for example, when user changes time or if clock is not synced, the countdown timer doesn't work as expected. 
Server time: 13:54
User time: 13:54
End date: 15:54, then countdown shows: **2(hrs):00(mins)**. But if:
Server time: 13:54
User time: 14:54 (it changed deliberately)
End date: 15:54, then countdown shows **1(hrs):00(mins)** as I want it be **2(hrs):00(mins)**. How can I do change this behavior? My goal is to achieve an independent countdown timer. Would you please give me hints about that?

### Edit

[Here](https://github.com/hilios/jQuery.countdown/blob/master/src/countdown.js#L215), the timer updates date. Is it reasonable to send request every time that update event fire?

Comment: You need to set the date to the server time, maybe something like this http://worldclockapi.com/ would help. Get a JSON of the current time.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to achieve? A full-client coutdown independent of server timezone (count one minute from a click for example), or a reliable coutdown that need to be synced with a server time? If you want the second, never trust a client time, and always refer to server time to check if the countdown expired or not (client time can change AFTER the timing has been set and that can be used to abuse the timer)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but by now, it works fine.

```
var now;
var it = 1;
now = new Date(Date.parse('@DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("u")'.replace(/ /g, "T")));
setInterval(setAndSyncTime, 1000);
function setAndSyncTime() {
    var t1 = new Date();
    var t2 = now;
    var t3 = Math.abs(t1 - t2);
    if (t3 > 2000) {
        if (it === 10) {
            it = 0;
            $.ajax({
                url: '/SyncTime',
                type: 'get',
                success: function (response) {
                    now = new Date(Date.parse(response.replace(/ /g, "T")));
                }
            });
        } else {
            now = now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + 1);
            now = new Date(now);
        }
    } else {
        now = now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + 1);
        now = new Date(now);
    }
    it++;
}
```

and

```
public virtual JsonResult SyncTime()
{
    return Json(DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("u"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```